# Replacing TableLayout with ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am currently using `TableLayout` inside `ScrollView` and Multiple `ListView` inside `TableRows` for getting following results.

[image]

**With following XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/progress_bar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_lbl_topSongs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/app_orange"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_topSongs"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Top Songs"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_content_topSongs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_topSongs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
                </ListView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_viewMore_topSongs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/app_offwhite"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_viewMore_topSongs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="View More"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_lbl_topVideos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/app_orange"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_topVideos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Top Videos"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_content_topVideos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_topVideos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
                </ListView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_viewMore_topVideos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/app_offwhite"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_viewMore_topVideos"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="View More"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_lbl_topRingtones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/app_orange"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_lbl_topRingtones"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Top Ringtones"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_content_topRingtones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_topRingtones"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
                </ListView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tr_viewMore_topRingtones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/app_offwhite"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_viewMore_topRingtones"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="View More"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/app_gray" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I done hacks on `ListView`s for Scroll issues created by Conflict of `ScrollView` and `ListView`. Now I realized that this is creating some mess with `NavigationDrawer` I want to shift to single `ListView` Approach. Is it possible? Any Example? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: @fiddler no. Letme check.